# Strange behaviour of shadowing in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow, shadow-mapping

so I have a threeJS scene, and I have some spheres (multimaterial) added. I have also a directional light added :

```
this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xFFFFFF, 1 );
this.light.position.set( 2, 10, 2 );  
this.light.castShadow = true;
this.light.shadowMapSoft = true;
this.light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
this.light.shadowCameraNear = 1;
this.light.shadowCameraFar = 10; 
this.light.shadowBias = 0.0009;
this.light.shadowDarkness = 0.3;
this.light.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
this.light.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
this.light.shadowCameraLeft = -8;
this.light.shadowCameraRight = 8;
this.light.shadowCameraTop = 8;
this.light.shadowCameraBottom = -8;
```

So when the user adds or removes spheres, a function which executes "reforms" the shadow camera frustum like this : 
[image]

```
    this.light.position.set( posV.x, posV.y, posV.z); 

    this.light.shadowCamera.far = l2*3;
    this.light.shadowCamera.left = -l2;
    this.light.shadowCamera.right = l2;
    this.light.shadowCamera.bottom = -l2;
    this.light.shadowCamera.top = l2;           
    this.light.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

and a possible result of the above code is this :

an other aspect of the exact situation of above :
 [image]

I have set the camera's frustum visibility to on, so there it is. The problem is the shadowing that is generated for no reason (pointed out by the red arrows). No other objects are in the scene at that moment and the spheres are fully inside the camera frustum.

Problems in shadowing like these are common after updating the spheres (add/remove), does anybody have any idea about it?

I use **three.js r72** ,
thanks!

Comment: It could be self-shadowing. Try adjusting the bias (positive and negative). I also suggest you update to the current version.

Comment: I tried a negative value and it seems that for now it works ok. But how can I be sure that in any case the shadows will behave ok?  I can't upgrade to r73 right now, you think it is vital for the shadows?

Comment: Also, how to avoid self-shadowing?

Comment: Many bugs are fixed with each release. Updating is your choice.

Comment: The only way to avoid self-shadowing artifacts is to adjust the bias parameter.

Comment: I see, thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, what you are seeing is self-shadowing artifacts.

You need to adjust the `shadowBias` ( now called `shadow.bias` ) parameter.

Varying the shadow bias results in a trade-off between "[peter-panning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416324(v=vs.85).aspx)" (too much positive bias) and self-shadowing artifacts (too much negative bias).

three.js r.73