# Artifacts in shadows, using standard MeshPhongMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

I'm having an issue regarding shadows.
Here is an image of the problem I'm facing:

[image: An image is waaay better than a thousand words]

[image]

I can't understand why there are those lines there, it's supposed to be completely lit! I don't get why the actual shadows appear to be really smooth, and the borders are good enough for what I'm trying to do, but then I have those lines all over the place.

My light configuration:

```
var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xfeffaf, 1);
dirLight.position.set(dimensions.middlePoint.x, 
    dimensions.middlePoint.y + ( dimensions.lengthY / 2),
    dimensions.middlePoint.z + dimensions.lengthZ);
dirLight.target.position.set(
    dimensions.middlePoint.x, 
    dimensions.middlePoint.y, 
    dimensions.minZ);
dirLight.castShadow = true;
dirLight.shadowDarkness = 0.4;
dirLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
dirLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
dirLight.shadowCameraNear = 1;
dirLight.shadowCameraFar = dimensions.lengthY * 2;
dirLight.shadowCameraLeft = - dimensions.lengthX / 2;
dirLight.shadowCameraRight = dimensions.lengthX / 2;
dirLight.shadowCameraTop = dimensions.lengthY / 2;
dirLight.shadowCameraBottom = -dimensions.lengthY / 2;
dirLight.shadowBias = 0.0000005;
scene.add(dirLight);
```

And then there's my render config:

```
threeRender = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
threeRender.shadowMap.enabled = true;
threeRender.shadowMap.renderReverseSided = false;
threeRender.shadowMapSoft = true;
threeRender.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

Please let me know how can I fix this, aswell as pointing me in the right direction towards fixing it. Thank you very much.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778864/strange-behaviour-of-shadowing-in-threejs/34779433#34779433

Comment: @WestLangley thank you very much. I've been since reading a lot and I came across with this [github issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6420). Has this been implemented? Can I give it a try? It seems to tackle performance and acne/petter-panning, so you can imagine why I'd like to give it a try.

Comment: I believe it has been implemented. Why don't you check and confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the value of your `shadowBias`. The artifact is known as shadow acne:

[image]

See [this link](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/) for more details.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought it was the other way around and kept on making it smaller! One thing though: Now I don't get any shadows :S

Comment: Increase shadowMap resolution (width and height), decrease the shadow frustum ( shadowCameraXXX...). ShadowCameraNear should be as large as possible.

Comment: The link you provided is of enormous help. I had no idea how to call the problem, that was my first issue (I couldn't search for it properly) Your solution was correct, although just pushing the value up didn't quite do the trick, as the shadows dissapeared. I negated it (-0.006) and everything now looks just great. Thank you so much though, I'm accepting your answer.